# Task not starting

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.4.3

I am using magento 2.4.3-p2 and created a cart price rule to give free delivery over £50. Since enabling this rule i get notifications at the top of the admin panel saying "Task "Rule processing: 2": 1 item(s) have been scheduled for update."

- In the bulk action log, these jobs have a status of "Not Started".
  -Cron is running and i have tried using "php bin/magento cron:run" with no change.
- I have tried using the command "php bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all" with no change.
- The fix about changing a db_schema.xml file doesnt apply to this version as its already been fixed.

RabbitMQ shows the async.operations.all queue which goes idle immediately after running "php bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all"

Does anyone have anything else i can try? No logs indicate anything is preventing the job from starting.

`ps aux | grep queue:consumers:start` returns:

````
user     3606801  0.0  0.9 573180 299588 ?       S    Aug17   2:08 /usr/bin/php7.4 /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor --single-thread --max-messages=100
user     3758173  0.0  0.5 456964 191800 ?       S    Aug18   0:46 /usr/bin/php7.4 /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus --single-thread --max-messages=10000
user     3758175  0.0  0.5 451952 169824 ?       S    Aug18   0:46 /usr/bin/php7.4 /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sales.rule.update.coupon.usage --single-thread --max-messages=5000
user 3868882  0.0  0.0   8168  2340 pts/0    S+   08:51   0:00 grep --color=auto queue:consumers:start```
````

Comment: I guess you need to proper configure queue consumers in your system. Looks like you have RabbitMQ. See https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/message-queues/manage-message-queues.html and https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/install-rabbitmq.html

Comment: queues are configured properly (as far as i can see). I've read both of those links numerous times. Magento connects to RabbitMQ ok as i see the connection when i try to manually run a queue in magento CLI.
vendor/magento/module-message-queue/etc/crontab.xml has not been edited

Comment: Cron should run and control consumer. Check if you have runned consumers like `ps aux | grep queue:consumers:start`. Try to set force `consumers_wait_for_messages` to 1.

Comment: I have added the output of `ps aux | grep queue:consumers:start` to my original post. I have tried with and without `consumers_wait_for_messages` set to 1 with no change